# How do I start a python application created in visual studio 2022

Tags: python

I saved my python app on desctop.
When I click on it opens up for a second and closes again.
It runs normally in visual studio.

Thanks in advance

the code is:

```
import secrets
import string
import pyperclip as pc

alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
password = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(15))  
pc.copy(password)
print (password)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `input` on the last line.

```py
import secrets
import string
import pyperclip as pc

alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
password = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(15))  
pc.copy(password)
print (password)  
input('Press Enter to Exit')
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is a scripting language, not something you make compiled "apps" with. You need to open the terminal/cmd prompt and call the script like so:

```
python my_python_file.py
```

Then you'll be able to see the output. FWIW the program *was* running. You just didn't call it from a terminal, so you couldn't see any output. Visual studio is handling this for you.